# How to use typings for d3-tip in typescript 2.0

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typing, definitelytyped

I want to use [d3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) library to add tooltips in my charts.

Using Typescript 2.0, I added the typings for `d3-tip` as follows:

```
npm install @types/d3-tip --save
```

It shows up in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/d3": "^4.7.0",
  "@types/d3-tip": "^3.5.4",
}
```

`index.d.ts` for d3-tip looks like this:

```
import {Primitive} from "d3";

declare module "d3" {
    type TooltipDirection = ("n" | "s" | "e" | "w" | "nw" | "ne" | "sw" | "se");
    interface Tooltip {
        hide(): Tooltip;
        show(): Tooltip;
        destroy(): Tooltip;
        ....
    }
    export function tip(): Tooltip;
}
```

My question is, how do I now use this/import in my code? I tried adding following:

```
import * as tip from 'd3-tip';   OR
import * from 'd3-tip';          OR
import { tip } from 'd3-tip';
```

but none of them work, and I don't get any intellisense on `d3.tip()`.

How do I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure anything out?

Comment: sorry no, had to use it without intellisense.

Comment: You mean it worked just by ignoring warning? Did it compile?

Answer (score 1):

Import, which works for me:

```
import d3Tip from "d3-tip";
const tip = d3Tip();
```

However, there is small discussion about this [here](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/issues/181).

Comment: It doesn't work. First intellisense gives a red underline for d3Tip in the import statement. Second, when I issue ng-serve it tells

ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(5,8): error TS1192: Module '"/Users/xyz/demo-proj/node_modules/@types/d3-tip/index"' has no default export.

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.